# Como evitar que aparezca un segundo cuadro de dialogo cuando ejecuto la funcion alert o confirm desde javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, yii

Tal como dice el titulo quiero saber si hay alguna forma de evitar que se duplique el cuadro de dialogo al usar dichas funciones, me encuentro en el siguiente dilema: quiero mostrar un mensaje de confirmacion en una pagina donde se hace un pago y en el mensaje tiene que mostrarse el monto que se pagó, en el framework que uso, se puede crear un widget, el cual entre sus atributos tiene uno que permite crear un cuadro de dialogo y este no se repite como cuando se crea el mensaje desde un script de JS, la cosa es que no logro hacer que me aparezca el monto enviado por el input cuando el mensaje de confirmacion lo invoco desde el widget, si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería.

Codigo del widget:

```
<?php 
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array('htmlOptions' => array('confirm' => '¿Está seguro que desea pagar y contabilizar el archivo?',)); 
?>
```

este es el código del boton con el atributo para imprimir el mensaje directo desde el widget. este me funciona pero no se como adjuntarle el valor que envio desde el input.

Codigo por JS:

```
function mensajeConfirmacion(){ 
    var monto_a_pagar = $(\'#'.CHtml::activeId($ComprobantePago,'monto_pagado').'\')‌​.val(); 
    var mensaje = confirm("¿Está seguro que desea pagar y contabilizar el archivo por Bs."+monto_a_pagar+"?"); 
    if (mensaje) { 
        activar_barra(); 
        return true; 
    }
    else { 
        return false; 
    } 
}
```

el problema con este es que se imprime 2 veces el mismo alert y el segundo alert me sobreescribe el valor obtenido en el primero.

Comment: Hola Frank, para poder ayudarte necesitas incluir un ejemplo básico de tu código y comentar que es lo que intentaste y que esperas obtener. Saludos.

Comment: @Frank Guerra  Edita la pregunta y añade el ejemplo. No todo el mundo lee los comentarios aparte de que aveces pueden quedar fuera de contexto y no son la mejor opción para mostrar código.

Comment: @Xerif listo, estaba por hacerlo pero me olvide ayer